# SQLite Filename cannot be null / undefined

Tags: javascript, sqlite, next.js

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxiQDo0CmDE&list=PLYSZyzpwBEWSQsrukurP09ksi49H9Yj40&index=4) tutorial where we're creaing an app using next.js. We're using sqlite, and testing a database. In the tutorial we write the following 'database-test.js' file:

```html
const sqlite = require('sqlite');

async function setup() {
    const db = await sqlite.open('./mydb.sqlite');
    await db.migrate({force: 'last'});

    const people = await db.all('SELECT * FROM person');
    console.log('ALL PEOPLE', JSON.stringify(people, null, 2));

    const vehicles = await db.all('SELECT * FROM vehicle');
    console.log('ALL VEHICLES', JSON.stringify(vehicles, null, 2));
}

setup();
```

I get the following error when I $node database-test.js:

```
(node:26446) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: sqlite: filename cannot be null / undefined
```

I don't really understand why we are opening a .sqlite file, and not a .db file. I've made sure I have the correct path to the .sqlite file. What is the cause of this error and how might I fix it? I can't seem to find any other documentation or examples of the .open function.

Comment: *"I don't really understand why we are opening a `.sqlite` file, and not a `.db` file."* - SQLite does not care one bit about how the file is called. Using `.sqlite` or `.db` as file extension is merely a convention. You could call it `.herbert` if you wanted to, it does not matter.

Comment: You need to provide details about which SQLite module you're using. Documentation can typically be found on the GitHub page for that module.

Answer (score 3):

As [@ANimator120](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12427268/animator120) was mentioned but with some tweaks.
Use require because it runs on server side.
Install sqlite3 by npm i sqlite3.
Then add path to your migrations folder if it's not in the project root.

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
const sqlite = require('sqlite');

async function openDb() {
  return sqlite.open({
    filename: './database.db',
    driver: sqlite3.Database,
  });
}

async function setup() {
  const db = await openDb();
  await db.migrate(
                    { 
                      migrationsPath: './src/migrations', //add cutom path to your migrations
                      force: 'last' 
                    }
                  );

  const people = await db.all('SELECT * FROM Person');
  console.log('all person', JSON.stringify(people, null, 2));

  const vehicle = await db.all(`SELECT a.*, b.* FROM Person as a
  LEFT JOIN Vehicle as b
  ON a.id = b.ownerId
  `);
  console.log('all vehicles', JSON.stringify(vehicle, null, 2));
}

setup();
```

Everything working fine, at least for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to npm install both sqlite and sqlite3
The correct way to use the open() method would be.

```
const sqlite = require('sqlite');
      const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3')
    const {open} = require('sqlite')

       async function openDB (){
    return open({
        filename : './mydb.sqlite',
        driver: sqlite3.Database
    })
}


async function setup(){
    const db = await openDB();
    await db.migrate({force : 'last'});
}

setup();
```

Answer (score 1):

1. **First of all Install sqlite3 using this `npm i --save sqlite3` terminal command**
2. In the JS file write down this code instead of yours

   ```
   const sqlite = require('sqlite');
   const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
   const {open} = require('sqlite');

   async function openDB (){
      return open({
         filename : './mydb.sqlite',
         driver: sqlite3.Database
      })
   }


   async function setup(){
       const db = await openDB();
       await db.migrate({force : 'last'});
   }

   setup();
   ```

But when executing this command line  `const people = await db.all('SELECT * FROM Person'); console.log("ALL PEOPLE", JSON.stringify(people, null, 2));` It shows me error that table person does not exist thats why i removed `DROP TABLE Person;` from migration file

Answer (score 0):

Turns out they were using sqlite 3.0.3 in the tutorial. With sqlite3, the correct way to use open() in this case is:

```html
import { open } from 'sqlite'
import sqlite3 from 'sqlite3'
 
// you would have to import / invoke this in another file
export async function openDB () {
  return open({
    filename: './mydb.sqlite',
    driver: sqlite3.Database
  })
}
```